# Is it possible to use "espeak" in system(" "); function?

Tags: c++, linux, function, system, espeak

Is it possible to use `espeak` in `system("");` function like `system("aplay 1.wav")` for example?

I like to use espeak in my C/C++ code inside Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: @n.m.: I have tried `system("espeak answer"); ` , but didn't work

Comment: If you can run a command from the shell, then a call to `system` with the same command should work too. You need to provide more details.

Answer (score 2):

You don’t use `espeak` “like `aplay`”, you use them together in the same command.

I believe you can use `espeak` in this way, but the syntax you use is incorrect.

You didn’t specify how you wanted to use `espeak`, but here are a couple options.

**Read quoted words:** `system("espeak --stdout 'words to speak' | aplay")`

**Read from text document:** `system("espeak --stdout -t mydocument.txt | aplay")`

[`espeak` reference page link](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/espeak-speech-synthesizer-for-ubuntu/#more-3120)

In the comments of your post you said you wanted  to use the command `system("espeak answer")`. Assuming `answer` is a string variable you can try this:

```
#include <string>

string answer, command;

command = "espeak --stdout '" + answer + "' | aplay";
system(command.c_str);
```

Comment: When I try `--stdout` option, it gives me strange characters without any sound!

Comment: Can you provide a screen dump? How do you wish to use espeak? What is `answer`? @user3486308